# TryInvokeMember doesn't fire if binder name is GetType(), or ToString(), etc

Tags: c#, object, dynamic, tryinvokemember

I'm just messing around with the C# 4.0 dynamic keyword, and got curious about one thing.

Suppose I have a class `DynamicWeirdness : DynamicObject`

Inside it I have a field named `reference` which is also of type `dynamic`. And a field named `referencetype` which is of type `Type`

This is my constructor:

```
public DynamicWeirdness(object reference)
{
        this.reference = reference;
        this.referencetype = reference.GetType();
}
```

If I ever try this:

```
public override bool TryInvokeMember(InvokeMemberBinder binder, object[] args, out object result)
{
    if (binder.Name == "GetType" && args.Length == 0)
    {
        result =  referencetype;
        return true;
    }
    result = null;
    return false;
}
```

When I call `GetType()` of a `DynamicWeirdness` object, it simply ignores my invocation and returns `{Name = "DynamicWeirdness" FullName = "Dynamic1.DynamicWeirdness"}`. Why?

I've tried with `ToString()`, `GetHashCode()`, and the same thing happens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The methods `GetType()`, `ToString()`, and `GetHashCode()` are all defined on `DynamicObject` (since it inherits from `System.Object`). When .NET goes to invoke those methods, it will just call them directly since they are defined on the object, and will skip the call to `TryInvokeMember`.

You can see this in action if you try calling a different method, like `Substring()`, and you'll see that `TryInvokeMember` on `DynamicWeirdness` does get called.

Instead of overriding `TryInvokeMember` on `DynamicWeirdness` to return a different type, you can just create a new `GetType()` method on `DynamicWeirdness`.

```
public new Type GetType()
{
    return this.referencetype;
}
```

For `GetHashCode()` and `ToString()`, you can override those members on `DynamicWeirdness` since they are marked as virtual.

Answer (score 3):

According to the [documentation for DynamicObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.dynamicobject.aspx):

> You can also add your own members to classes derived from the DynamicObject class. If your
>   class defines properties and also overrides the TrySetMember method, the dynamic language
>   runtime (DLR) first uses the language binder to look for a static definition of a property
>   in the class. If there is no such property, the DLR calls the TrySetMember method.

Since DynamicObject inherits from Object, any methods of Object will preclude TryInvokeMember from processing the call.

Comment: +1 That makes complete sense. Wish I could mark both answers as answer.